# When I am webscraping prices off of this website using BeautifulSoup why does the output not match the html code when I press inspect?

Tags: python, web-scraping

The output does not match the html code when I click inspect on the website. Is the way i set up my code correct? Here is my code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#making soup
url='https://shop.thefreshmarket.com/shop/categories/75'
headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac 
OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) 
Chrome/47.0.2526.80 Safari/537.36'}
resp=requests.get (url, headers=headers)
html=resp.text
soup=BeautifulSoup (html, "html.parser")
print(soup.prettify())

#finding tags
tagged_values=soup.find_all ("span",{'class':"css- 
1v2rf20"})
print (tagged_values)
values=[x.get_text () for x in tagged_values]
for value in values:
    print (value)
print ('\n')
#website:https://shop.thefreshmarket.com/shop/categories/75
```

Comment: what do you expect as output? and what do you get as ouput?

Comment: I am expecting a list of prices for the tagged_values but I just get [] as the output. For the soup I expected to get the html code for the website but instead I get a very long list of random code that I do not recognize (I am new to coding). There are bits and pieces that are similar to the website's html code but there are not class headers in my output and I need the soup to contain the specific price class I am looking for